# Unable to run "nvm install --lts"

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nodejs, npm

I get this error.

```
Installing latest LTS version.
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Version '' (with LTS filter) not found - try `nvm ls-remote --lts` to browse available versions.
```

I am on WSL Ubuntu, Windows 10 19044.2251

Answer (score 1):

I put this post directly as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

I think the problem could be that you don't have the libkeyutils-dev library installed. You can install it with the following command.

```
sudo apt install libkeyutils-dev
```

Try this solution and let us know if it worked for you or not.

Comment: IMHO this is perfectly fine as an answer, since you are making an honest attempt to answer the question.  You are correct that normally we'd probably put it as a comment asking the OP if they'd tried that yet.  However, since you don't have the rep to do so yet, it's fine as an answer in this case.  Thanks!

Comment: When I run that command, I get `sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?
sudo: a password is required`

Comment: You get that answer because when executing some linux commands you need to have an account with administrator privileges (called root).

When you installed a Linux distribution, you had to set a password for that account. You must review it.